# Resize image does gives no method error carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am trying to have different versions of the uploaded image with different resolutions. Here is the model in which I am mounting carrierwave uploader

```
 class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :image, ResizeUploader
 end
```

Here is the mounting model

```
class ResizeUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  #storage :file
  storage :fog

  process resize_to_fit: [800, 800]

  version :tablet do
    process resize_to_fill: [200,200]
  end  

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [280, 280]
  end



  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.split("::").last.downcase}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end


  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    %w(pdf doc xdoc jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

The `Offer.last.thumb.url` gives me no method error. Should I need to have a column named thumb in my offer? What am I missing here?

Comment: I think you should pass column name like this: offer.last.image.thumb.url

Comment: You are correct ... I can happily accept your answer .. if you mind writing one :) Thanks

Comment: you are welcome @gates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should pass column name like this:

```
offer.last.image.thumb.url
```